# Unable to connect to instance through SSH in google compute engine , another instance of same account works fine

Tags: ssh, google-compute-engine, google-cloud-platform

I am trying to connect to my instance using gcloud compute ssh new-instance .. it's gives the following error:

```
ssh: connect to host 107.167.180.68 port 22: Connection refused
ERROR: (gcloud.compute.ssh) [/usr/bin/ssh] exited with return code [255].  
See https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/troubleshooting#ssherrors for troubleshooting hints.
```

I had already tried all the possible solution mentioned in the [google document](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/troubleshooting).

Any suggestions on how to get a backup of the Database and file? The site has been down for the last two days

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 2):

I'd recommend looking at the serial console output of the VM instance using `gcloud compute instances get-serial-port-ouput` or using "View serial port" button on the instance page in Cloud Console.  That output should give you information about what is wrong with the VM, such as whether it runs out of memory or ran out of disk space or something like that.  Also, make sure you didn't change the VM's network firewall rules to accidentally disallow incoming traffic on port 22.

The documentation page for SSH from the Browser also has some additional tips on how to explore this kind of issues - see [here](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/ssh-in-browser#ssherror) and [here](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/ssh-in-browser#couldnotconnecterror).

Answer (score 0):

You can use the ssh keys with other instances of your account if you update the ssh keys in your metadata by

```
sudo gcloud compute config-ssh
```